# Install Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: 20.10, mssql

I have a problem when I follow steps to install ms-SQL-serve on ubuntu the steps in the below link:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15

I face the below error in step 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 330, in <module>
    addaptrepo = AddAptRepository()
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 35, in __init__
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 91, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException(
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Ubuntu/groovy
```

any solution

Comment: See the "You must have an Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 machine with at least 2 GB of memory.". That does not list 20.10.  You need the mssql installer for 20.10. https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.10/ so change your download to download the one from the link

Comment: in this [Link](https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.10/) i'm not fount any sql-serve (2017,2019) .list , so what can i do now?

Comment: You must have an Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 that mean uninstall the current ubuntu and install the 18.04  version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your Ubuntu.info file doesn't have a 'groovy' entry. Because of a bug in python-apt-common.

Good news. It was fixed today.
Just do a

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```